# The Spring source project cannot run after deleting module

Tags: spring

Configure spring source code, add modules to spring, after deleting the added module, error Basedir D:\Spring_LOCAL\spring-framework-5.3.x\springTestDemo does not exist
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAJD8.png)

I tried to delete the module from the project structure and found that I couldn't click Delete module and gradle couldn't delete it either.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmLBa.png)

Comment: not sure what exactly you are trying to do, but did you run `gradle clean build` to get a clean build?

Comment: ok,thank you,I fixed the settings.gradle,it can run,thsk you